# How to connect a music and a SFX on/ off button from 2 .m files (with 2 .xibs) with audio from a singleton class

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I´ve created a singleton class for handling the background music and SFX for the puzzle game that I´m creating. The class works fine inside the game. The music starts and stops as well as the SFX but I have an issue with connecting them to the ON/OFF buttons in the options menu on the main menu.xib (main menu.m).

I´m not able to turn them on and off from the main menu.xib as well as getting the buttons inside the game (on the game.xib(game.m)) to react to the choices made in the main menu. same thing the other way around. Not able to get the buttons in the main menu to know if the music or SFX was turned off inside the game.

is there a way to conenct them somehow?

or maybe any other suggestions?

Ps. i get warning messages as well from the sharedSoundManager part. The warnings say "may not respond". Am I missing anything? ( I called sharedSoundManager from viewDidLoad like this sharedSoundManager = [SingletonSoundManager sharedSoundManager];)

```
-(IBAction)SFX{

//ChangeSFX = [[MainMenu alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainMenu" bundle: nil];

if(sfx2.hidden){
    NSLog(@"SFX Stops");
    sfx1.hidden = YES;
    sfx2.hidden = NO;
    [sharedSoundManager stopSoundWithKey:@"movingbricks"];

}
else if(sfx1.hidden){
    NSLog(@"SFX Starts");
    sfx1.hidden = NO;
    sfx2.hidden = YES;
    [sharedSoundManager playSoundWithKey:@"movingbricks" gain:0.13f pitch:1.0f shouldLoop:NO];

}
```

}

```
-(IBAction)MUSIC{

if(music2.hidden){
    NSLog(@"Music Stops");
    music1.hidden = YES;
    music2.hidden = NO;
    [sharedSoundManager pausePlayingMusic];
}
else if(music1.hidden){
    NSLog(@"Music Starts");
    music1.hidden = NO;
    music2.hidden = YES;
    [sharedSoundManager resumePlayingMusic];
}
```

}

UPDATE_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*____**
My singleton Sound Manager class

```
#import "SingletonSoundManager.h"

@interface SingletonSoundManager (Private)
- (BOOL)initOpenAL;
- (NSUInteger) nextAvailableSource;
- (AudioFileID) openAudioFile:(NSString*)theFilePath;
- (UInt32) audioFileSize:(AudioFileID)fileDescriptor;
@end


@implementation SingletonSoundManager

// This var will hold our Singleton class instance that will be handed to anyone who asks for it
static SingletonSoundManager *sharedSoundManager = nil;

// Class method which provides access to the sharedSoundManager var.
+ (SingletonSoundManager *)sharedSoundManager {

    // synchronized is used to lock the object and handle multiple threads accessing this method at
    // the same time
    @synchronized(self) {

        // If the sharedSoundManager var is nil then we need to allocate it.
        if(sharedSoundManager == nil) {
            // Allocate and initialize an instance of this class
            [[self alloc] init];
        }
    }

    // Return the sharedSoundManager
    return sharedSoundManager;
}


/* This is called when you alloc an object.  To protect against instances of this class being
 allocated outside of the sharedSoundManager method, this method checks to make sure 
 that the sharedSoundManager is nil before allocating and initializing it.  If it is not
 nil then nil is returned and the instance would need to be obtained through the sharedSoundManager method
 */
+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (sharedSoundManager == nil) {
            sharedSoundManager = [super allocWithZone:zone];
            return sharedSoundManager;  // assignment and return on first allocation
        }
    }
    return nil; //on subsequent allocation attempts return nil
}


- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    return self;
}


/* 
 When the init is called from the sharedSoundManager class method, this method will get called.
 This is where we then initialize the arrays and dictionaries which will store the OpenAL buffers
 create as well as the soundLibrary dictionary
 */
- (id)init {
    if(self = [super init]) {
        soundSources = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        soundLibrary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        musicLibrary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

        // Set the default volume for music
        backgroundMusicVolume = 1.0f;

        // Set up the OpenAL
        BOOL result = [self initOpenAL];
        if(!result) return nil;
        return self;
    }
    [self release];
    return nil;
}


/*
 This method is used to initialize OpenAL.  It gets the default device, creates a new context 
 to be used and then preloads the define # sources.  This preloading means we wil be able to play up to
 (max 32) different sounds at the same time
 */
- (BOOL) initOpenAL {
    // Get the device we are going to use for sound.  Using NULL gets the default device
    device = alcOpenDevice(NULL);

    // If a device has been found we then need to create a context, make it current and then
    // preload the OpenAL Sources
    if(device) {
        // Use the device we have now got to create a context "air"
        context = alcCreateContext(device, NULL);
        // Make the context we have just created into the active context
        alcMakeContextCurrent(context);
        // Pre-create 32 sound sources which can be dynamically allocated to buffers (sounds)
        NSUInteger sourceID;
        for(int index = 0; index < kMaxSources; index++) {
            // Generate an OpenAL source
            alGenSources(1, &sourceID);
            // Add the generated sourceID to our array of sound sources
            [soundSources addObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:sourceID]];
        }

        // Return YES as we have successfully initialized OpenAL
        return YES;
    }
    // Something went wrong so return NO
    return NO;
}

- (void) shutdownSoundManager {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if(sharedSoundManager != nil) {
            [self dealloc];
        }
    }
}


- (void) loadSoundWithKey:(NSString*)theSoundKey fileName:(NSString*)theFileName fileExt:(NSString*)theFileExt frequency:(NSUInteger)theFrequency {

    // Get the full path of the audio file
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:theFileName ofType:theFileExt];

    // Now we need to open the file
    AudioFileID fileID = [self openAudioFile:filePath];

    // Find out how big the actual audio data is
    UInt32 fileSize = [self audioFileSize:fileID];

    // Create a location for the audio data to live temporarily
    unsigned char *outData = malloc(fileSize);

    // Load the byte data from the file into the data buffer
    OSStatus result = noErr;
    result = AudioFileReadBytes(fileID, FALSE, 0, &fileSize, outData);
    AudioFileClose(fileID);

    if(result != 0) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR SoundEngine: Cannot load sound: %@", theFileName);
        return;
    }

    NSUInteger bufferID;

    // Generate a buffer within OpenAL for this sound
    alGenBuffers(1, &bufferID);

    // Place the audio data into the new buffer
    alBufferData(bufferID, AL_FORMAT_STEREO16, outData, fileSize, theFrequency);

    // Save the buffer to be used later
    [soundLibrary setObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:bufferID] forKey:theSoundKey];

    // Clean the buffer
    if(outData) {
        free(outData);
        outData = NULL;
    }
}


- (void) loadBackgroundMusicWithKey:(NSString*)theMusicKey fileName:(NSString*)theFileName fileExt:(NSString*)theFileExt {

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:theFileName ofType:theFileExt];
    [musicLibrary setObject:path forKey:theMusicKey];
}


/*
 Used to load an audiofile from the file path which is provided.
 */
- (AudioFileID) openAudioFile:(NSString*)theFilePath {

    AudioFileID outAFID;
    // Create an NSURL which will be used to load the file.  This is slightly easier
    // than using a CFURLRef
    NSURL *afUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:theFilePath];

    // Open the audio file provided
    OSStatus result = AudioFileOpenURL((CFURLRef)afUrl, kAudioFileReadPermission, 0, &outAFID);

    // If we get a result that is not 0 then something has gone wrong.  We report it and 
    // return the out audio file id
    if(result != 0) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR SoundEngine: Cannot open file: %@", theFilePath);
        return nil;
    }

    return outAFID;
}


/*
 This helper method returns the file size in bytes for a given AudioFileID
 */
- (UInt32) audioFileSize:(AudioFileID)fileDescriptor {
    UInt64 outDataSize = 0;
    UInt32 thePropSize = sizeof(UInt64);
    OSStatus result = AudioFileGetProperty(fileDescriptor, kAudioFilePropertyAudioDataByteCount, &thePropSize, &outDataSize);
    if(result != 0) NSLog(@"ERROR: cannot file file size");
    return (UInt32)outDataSize;
}


/*
 Plays the sound which matches the key provided.  The Gain, pitch and if the sound should loop can
 also be set from the method signature
 */
- (NSUInteger) playSoundWithKey:(NSString*)theSoundKey gain:(ALfloat)theGain pitch:(ALfloat)thePitch shouldLoop:(BOOL)theShouldLoop {

    ALenum err = alGetError(); // clear the error code

    // Find the buffer linked to the key which has been passed in
    NSNumber *numVal = [soundLibrary objectForKey:theSoundKey];
    if(numVal == nil) return 0;
    NSUInteger bufferID = [numVal unsignedIntValue];

    // Find an available source i.e. it is currently not playing anything
    NSUInteger sourceID = [self nextAvailableSource];

    // Make sure that the source is clean by resetting the buffer assigned to the source
    // to 0
    alSourcei(sourceID, AL_BUFFER, 0);
    //Attach the buffer we have looked up to the source we have just found
    alSourcei(sourceID, AL_BUFFER, bufferID);

    // Set the pitch and gain of the source
    alSourcef(sourceID, AL_PITCH, thePitch);
    alSourcef(sourceID, AL_GAIN, theGain);

    // Set the looping value
    if(theShouldLoop) {
        alSourcei(sourceID, AL_LOOPING, AL_TRUE);
    } else {
        alSourcei(sourceID, AL_LOOPING, AL_FALSE);
    }

    // Check to see if there were any errors
    err = alGetError();
    if(err != 0) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR SoundManager: %d", err);
        return 0;
    }

    // Now play the sound
    alSourcePlay(sourceID);

    // Return the source ID so that loops can be stopped etc
    return sourceID;
}


- (void) stopSoundWithKey:(NSString*)theSoundKey {

    // Reset errors in OpenAL
    ALenum alError = alGetError();
    alError = AL_NO_ERROR;

    // Find the buffer which has been linked to the sound key provided
    NSNumber *numVal = [soundLibrary objectForKey:theSoundKey];

    // If the key is not found log it and finish
    if(numVal == nil) {
        NSLog(@"WARNING - SoundManager: No sound with key '%@' was found so cannot be stopped", theSoundKey);
        return;
    }

    // Get the buffer number from
    NSUInteger bufferID = [numVal unsignedIntValue];
    NSInteger bufferForSource;
    for(NSNumber *sourceID in soundSources) {

        NSUInteger currentSourceID = [sourceID unsignedIntValue];

        // Grab the buffer currently bound to this source
        alGetSourcei(currentSourceID, AL_BUFFER, &bufferForSource);

        // If the buffer matches the buffer we want to stop then stop the source and unbind it from the buffer
        if(bufferForSource == bufferID) {
            alSourceStop(currentSourceID);
            alSourcei(currentSourceID, AL_BUFFER, 0);
        }
    } 

    // Check for any errors
    if((alError = alGetError()) != AL_NO_ERROR)
        NSLog(@"ERROR - SoundManager: Could not stop sound with key '%@' got error %x", theSoundKey, alError);

}


/*
 Play the background track which matches the key
 */
- (void) playMusicWithKey:(NSString*)theMusicKey timesToRepeat:(NSUInteger)theTimesToRepeat {

    NSError *error;

    NSString *path = [musicLibrary objectForKey:theMusicKey];

    if(!path) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR SoundEngine: The music key '%@' could not be found", theMusicKey);
        return;
    }

    // Initialize the AVAudioPlayer
    backgroundMusicPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:&error];

    // If the backgroundMusicPlayer object is nil then there was an error
    if(!backgroundMusicPlayer) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR SoundManager: Could not play music for key '%d'", error);
        return;
    }       

    // Set the number of times this music should repeat.  -1 means never stop until its asked to stop
    [backgroundMusicPlayer setNumberOfLoops:theTimesToRepeat];

    // Set the volume of the music
    [backgroundMusicPlayer setVolume:backgroundMusicVolume];

    // Play the music
    [backgroundMusicPlayer play];


}


/*
 Stop playing the currently playing music
 */
- (void) stopPlayingMusic{
    [backgroundMusicPlayer stop];
}

- (void) pausePlayingMusic{
    [backgroundMusicPlayer pause];
}

- (void) resumePlayingMusic{
    [backgroundMusicPlayer play];
}


/*
 Set the volume of the music which is between 0.0 and 1.0
 */
- (void) setBackgroundMusicVolume:(ALfloat)theVolume {

    // Set the volume iVar
    backgroundMusicVolume = theVolume;

    // Check to make sure that the audio player exists and if so set its volume
    if(backgroundMusicPlayer) {
        [backgroundMusicPlayer setVolume:backgroundMusicVolume];

    }
}


/* 
 Search through the max number of sources to find one which is not planning.  If one cannot
 be found that is not playing then the first one which is looping is stopped and used instead.
 If a source still cannot be found then the first source is stopped and used
 */
- (NSUInteger) nextAvailableSource {

    // Holder for the current state of the current source
    NSInteger sourceState;

    // Find a source which is not being used at the moment
    for(NSNumber *sourceNumber in soundSources) {
        alGetSourcei([sourceNumber unsignedIntValue], AL_SOURCE_STATE, &sourceState);
        // If this source is not playing then return it
        if(sourceState != AL_PLAYING) return [sourceNumber unsignedIntValue];
    }

    // If all the sources are being used we look for the first non looping source
    // and use the source associated with that
    NSInteger looping;
    for(NSNumber *sourceNumber in soundSources) {
        alGetSourcei([sourceNumber unsignedIntValue], AL_LOOPING, &looping);
        if(!looping) {
            // We have found a none looping source so return this source and stop checking
            NSUInteger sourceID = [sourceNumber unsignedIntValue];
            alSourceStop(sourceID);
            return sourceID;
        }
    }

    // If there are no looping sources to be found then just use the first sounrce and use that
    NSUInteger sourceID = [[soundSources objectAtIndex:0] unsignedIntegerValue];
    alSourceStop(sourceID);
    return sourceID;
}


- (id)retain {
    return self;
}


- (unsigned)retainCount {
    return UINT_MAX;  //denotes an object that cannot be released
} 


- (void)release {
    //do nothing
}


- (id)autorelease {
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    // Loop through the OpenAL sources and delete them
    for(NSNumber *numVal in soundSources) {
        NSUInteger sourceID = [numVal unsignedIntValue];
        alDeleteSources(1, &sourceID);
    }

    // Loop through the OpenAL buffers and delete 
    NSEnumerator *enumerator = [soundLibrary keyEnumerator];
    id key;
    while ((key = [enumerator nextObject])) {
        NSNumber *bufferIDVal = [soundLibrary objectForKey:key];
        NSUInteger bufferID = [bufferIDVal unsignedIntValue];
        alDeleteBuffers(1, &bufferID);      
    }

    // Release the arrays and dictionaries we have been using
    [soundLibrary release];
    [soundSources release];
    [musicLibrary release];

    // Disable and then destroy the context
    alcMakeContextCurrent(NULL);
    alcDestroyContext(context);

    // Close the device
    alcCloseDevice(device);

    [super dealloc];
}

@end


//My SFX and Music methods from the game.m class



    -(IBAction)SFX{

    BOOL buttonState = [SingletonSoundManager isSFXOn]; //generated "may not respond" warnings. why?
           //BOOL buttonState = [SingletonSoundManager isSFXOn]:
    [SingletonSoundManager setSFXOn:!buttonState]; //generated "may not respond" warnings. why?



    if(sfx2.hidden){
        NSLog(@"SFX Stops");
        sfx1.hidden = buttonState;
        sfx2.hidden = !buttonState;
        [sharedSoundManager stopSoundWithKey:@"movingbricks"]; //generated "may not respond" warnings. why?

    }
    else if(sfx1.hidden){
        NSLog(@"SFX Starts");
        sfx1.hidden = buttonState;
        sfx2.hidden = !buttonState;
        [sharedSoundManager playSoundWithKey:@"movingbricks" gain:0.13f pitch:1.0f shouldLoop:NO]; //generated "may not respond" warnings. why?



    }
}

-(IBAction)MUSIC{
    BOOL buttonState = [SingletonSoundManager isMusicOn]; //generated "may not respond" warnings. why?
           //BOOL buttonState = [SingletonSoundManager resumePlayingMusic];
    [SingletonSoundManager setMusicOn:!buttonState]; //generated "may not respond" warnings. why?
          //[SingletonSoundManager pausePlayingMusic:!buttonState]; 


    if(music2.hidden){
        NSLog(@"Music Stops");
        music1.hidden = buttonState;
        music2.hidden = buttonState;
        [sharedSoundManager pausePlayingMusic]; //generated "may not respond" warnings. why?


    }
    else if(music1.hidden){
        NSLog(@"Music Starts");
        music1.hidden = buttonState;
        music2.hidden = !buttonState;
        [sharedSoundManager resumePlayingMusic]; //generated "may not respond" warnings. why?


    }
}

//My SFX and Music methods inside my mainmenu.m class

    //Turn on and off the SFX
-(IBAction)SFXswap{

    BOOL buttonState = [SingletonSoundManager isSFXOn];  //generated "may not respond" warnings. why?

    [SingletonSoundManager setSFXOn:!buttonState];  //generated "may not respond" warnings. why?



    if(sfx2.hidden){
        NSLog(@"SFX Stops");
        sfx1.hidden = buttonState;
        sfx2.hidden = buttonState;
        [sharedSoundManager stopSoundWithKey:@"movingbricks"]; //generated "may not respond" warnings. why?


    }
    else if(sfx1.hidden){
        NSLog(@"SFX Starts");
        sfx1.hidden = buttonState;
        sfx2.hidden = buttonState;
        [sharedSoundManager playSoundWithKey:@"movingbricks" gain:0.13f pitch:1.0f shouldLoop:NO]; //generated "may not respond" warnings. why?


    }
}

//Turn on and off the backgrund music
-(IBAction)MUSICswap{

    BOOL buttonState = [SingletonSoundManager isMusicOn];  //generated "may not respond" warnings. why?
           //BOOL buttonState = [SingletonSoundManager resumePlayingMusic];
    [SingletonSoundManager setMusicOn:!buttonState];  //generated "may not respond" warnings. why?
           //[SingletonSoundManager pausePlayingMusic:!buttonState]; 



    if(music2.hidden){
        NSLog(@"Music Stops");
        music1.hidden = buttonState;
        music2.hidden = !buttonState;
        [sharedSoundManager pausePlayingMusic]; //generated "may not respond" warnings. why?


    }
    else if(music1.hidden){
        NSLog(@"Music Starts");
        music1.hidden = buttonState;
        music2.hidden = !buttonState;
        [sharedSoundManager resumePlayingMusic]; //generated "may not respond" warnings. why?


    }
}


if this how you meant, Ravin? Please corret me if i´m wrong :)


------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------NEW UPDATE
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    //In singletonSoundManager.h

BOOL isMusicOn; 

- (BOOL) isMusicOn; 
- (void) setMusicOn:(BOOL)boolValue; 


//In singletonSoundManager.m

- (void) playMusicWithKey:(NSString*)theMusicKey timesToRepeat:(NSUInteger)theTimesToRepeat {

    NSError *error;

    NSString *path = [musicLibrary objectForKey:theMusicKey];

    if(!path) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR SoundEngine: The music key '%@' could not be found", theMusicKey);
        return;
    }

    // Initialize the AVAudioPlayer
    backgroundMusicPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:&error];

    // If the backgroundMusicPlayer object is nil then there was an error
    if(!backgroundMusicPlayer) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR SoundManager: Could not play music for key '%d'", error);
        return;
    }        

    // Set the number of times this music should repeat.  -1 means never stop until its asked to stop
    [backgroundMusicPlayer setNumberOfLoops:theTimesToRepeat];

    // Set the volume of the music
    [backgroundMusicPlayer setVolume:backgroundMusicVolume];

    // Play the music
    [backgroundMusicPlayer play];

    isMusicOn = YES;
}

-(BOOL)isMusicOn 
{ 
    return isMusicOn; 
} 

-(void)setMusicOn:(BOOL)boolValue 
{ 
    isMusicOn = boolValue; 
} 


/*
 Stop playing the currently playing music
 */
- (void) stopPlayingMusic{
    [backgroundMusicPlayer stop];
}

- (void) pausePlayingMusic{
    [backgroundMusicPlayer pause];
    isMusicOn = NO;
}

- (void) resumePlayingMusic{
    [backgroundMusicPlayer play];
    isMusicOn = YES;
}


//In game.m 


-(IBAction)MUSIC{

    BOOL buttonstate = [SingletonSoundManager isMusicOn]; // "SingletonSoundManager may not respond to isMusicOn" 
                                                                                       //" Initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast"

    [SingletonSoundManager setMusicOn:!buttonstate]; //"SingletonSoundManager may not respond to setMusicOn"

    if(music2.hidden){
        NSLog(@"Music Stops");
        music1.hidden = buttonstate;
        music2.hidden = !buttonstate;

        [sharedSoundManager pausePlayingMusic]; //"SingletonSoundManager may not respond to pausePlayingMusic"

    }
    else if(music1.hidden){
        NSLog(@"Music Starts");
        music1.hidden = !buttonstate;
        music2.hidden = buttonstate;

        [sharedSoundManager resumePlayingMusic]; //"SingletonSoundManager may not respond to resumePlayingMusic"
    }
}


in mainmenu.m
-(IBAction)MUSICswap{

    BOOL buttonstate = [SingletonSoundManager isMusicOn]; // "SingletonSoundManager may not respond to isMusicOn" 
                                                                                       //" Initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast"

    [SingletonSoundManager setMusicOn:!buttonstate]; //"SingletonSoundManager may not respond to setMusicOn"

    if(music2.hidden){
        NSLog(@"Music Stops");
        //music1.hidden = YES;
        //music2.hidden = NO;
        music1.hidden = buttonstate;
        music2.hidden = !buttonstate;
        [sharedSoundManager pausePlayingMusic]; //"SingletonSoundManager may not respond to pausePlayingMusic"
    }
    else if(music1.hidden){
        NSLog(@"Music Starts");
        //music1.hidden = NO;
        //music2.hidden = YES;
        music1.hidden = !buttonstate;
        music2.hidden = buttonstate;
        [sharedSoundManager resumePlayingMusic]; //"SingletonSoundManager may not respond to resumePlayingMusic"
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is not completely clear to me. I do not understand what do you mean by connecting with button? but one thing I guessed that you need some way to attach action with button in different class? button have method addTarget: which helps in adding action with it.

Comment: Sorry if the question was unclear. What I meant was that I have a singleton class called singletonsoundmanager.m. then i have a mainmenu.m file (and a mainmenu.xib) where I have sound options for the game. I have also a game.m (and a game.xib) where the actual puzzlegame takes place on. I need to connect the singleton class to both the the mainmenu.m and the game.m to be able to turn on/off the music and the sfx.

Comment: I want also the buttons that represent on/off in both the classes (and their .xib files) to "know" when the button is accessed in the other class. In other words... if I press turn off music in the game (game.xib/.m) then the button in the mainmenu (mainmenu.xib/.m) will say "aha... the music or the sfx has been turne dof in the game then I shall switch to off as well" and then turn the image of the button to off so if i go back to the mainmenu the musicbutton will appear as off as "default". hope this was more clearer and not more confusing:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using singleton class so maintain there a flag(musicOn) which will take care of the button state(make it a property so that you can set and get it). If you are using UIButton then you can do it as follows.

```
-(IBAction)SFX{

//ChangeSFX = [[MainMenu alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainMenu" bundle: nil];
//get object of singletonClass for flag access
BOOL buttonState = [singletonClassObject isMusicOn];
[singletonClassObject setMusicOn:!buttonState];
if(sfx2.hidden){
    NSLog(@"SFX Stops");
    sfx1.hidden = buttonState;
    sfx2.hidden = !buttonState;
    [sharedSoundManager stopSoundWithKey:@"movingbricks"];

}
else if(sfx1.hidden){
    NSLog(@"SFX Starts");
    sfx1.hidden = !buttonState;
    sfx2.hidden = buttonState;
    [sharedSoundManager playSoundWithKey:@"movingbricks" gain:0.13f pitch:1.0f shouldLoop:NO];

}
```

please recheck the hidden property setting, I am not sure how you wish to use them.

**NEWLY UPDATE**

in your **singleton class's .h**

in variable declartion add

```
BOOL isMusicOn;
```

in method declartion add

```
+(BOOL) isMusicOn;
+(void) setMusicOn:(BOOL)boolValue;
```

in **singleton class's .m**

```
+(BOOL)isMusicOn
{
 return isMusicOn;
}

+(void)setMusicOn:(BOOL)boolValue
{
 isMusicOn = boolValue;
}
```

also in your initialization method please set `isMusicOn` variable `YES` or `NO` as you wish.

Thanks,

Comment: Hey! thanx. I´ll try it out and let you know how it went. :) ps. do you maybe know or have an idea of why I get warning on my sharedsoundmanagers in the -(IBACTION)SFX and -(IBACTION)MUSIC methods?

Comment: By the way... thig might be a stupid question but... can I use this on both my game.m and my mainmenu.m classes? (since I have buttons in both .xib files).

Comment: accordingly to the code you provided me with? got it ;)

will try it out tonight and get back to you ;)

Comment: It didn´t work :( I´ve tried the way to showed me and I´ve tried as well to change the BOOL buttonState = [SingletonMusicManager isMusicOn]; to BOOL buttonState = [SingletonMusicManager resumePlayingMusic]; and the [SingletonMusicManager setMusicOn:!buttonState]; to  [SingletonMusicManager pausePlayingMusic:!buttonState]; just in case I missunderstood your code but I got the same warnings as I do with my  [sharedSoundManager stopSoundWithKey:@"movingbricks"]; etc . which is "May not respond"- . I got the messages everytime but I could still build and run it. The game crashed though

Comment: when I pressed the buttons during the game. the code below shows the singleton class and how I modified code in my game.m and in my mainmenu.m

Comment: it seems that I´m not allowed (yet) to put a answer to my own thread so I´ve edit the the quesion above with my singleton class and sfx and music methods from the game.m and the mainmenu.m classes

Comment: are stopSoundWithKey and other methods defined in your Singleton class? in header file?

Comment: but, changes are not reflected.have you changed methods definition?

Comment: yes they are. I´ve put the singleton class in the "question" above :)

Comment: ehm... I just did how you explained in your code. I guess I missed something :(

Comment: which method sharedManager do not have? isMusicOn or setMusicOn? have you created these methods?

Comment: no I haven´t that´s why I tried with the once I already had. I replaced the ismusicOn with the resumePlayingmusic method and the setmusonon with the pausemusic method that I have in the singletonclass. shouldn´t I have done that? ps. this is the first time I use a singleton class

Comment: ok tell have you added the flag as I mentioned in ansered and two methods for setting and getting it? what is the name of flag and methods? how do you define them?

Comment: Like I said I just did how you showed me in the code above, nothing more nothing less. I´m still learning iphone development so there still may be some stuff that I miss. the code is is the "original" question as an update. there you can see exactly what I did...

Comment: Please can you tell me do you have any method isMusicOn and setMusic in your singleton class? as code is not formatted properly in your post so its bit difficult to check it.

Comment: sorry for that. I seem to have problem getting all the code inside the code tags. like I said before, I don´t have those methods. Should I have had them from the beginning (The tutorial I used for creating the singleton class didn´t use those two methods) or create them after you showed me how to solve this issue?

Comment: hey these methods are our own we need to add them, and thats the problem.(currently I am considering your question and subsequent problems not the singleton issue) so please do add those methods as I am doing in updated code above.

Comment: ok I´ll put the two methods in my singleton class.  :) do i need one for the SFX as well or shall we use the once we create? should they be void methods? what shall I put in them? sorry for all of these noob-questions but I have no idea how these methods you want me to create work :(

Comment: please see updated code in answer.are you having problem in that?

Comment: aa no I see it. sorry about that. my website didn´t update it all when i read your comment so i just saw your comment and not the updated code :) I´ll do that and get back to you. thanx for baring with me so far. appreciate it. thanx for all the help

Comment: I created the two methods, isMusicOn and setMusicOn but I got several warnings in the MusicSwap and music methods inside the mainmenu.m and in the game.m files. I´ve updated the code above with the modified once. I´ve put in where and what the warnings said. The game crashed as soon as I pressed on the Music ON/OFF button in the main menu and inside the game. What am I still doing wrong? You can see where I´ve initialized the isMusicOn in the updated code above. ps. I cannot seem to get the code tags to work properly when updating my thread with new code :(

Comment: I declared these methods as instance methods Now I have corrected them in above code. Note the plus sign before the methods.Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: thanx. I´ll try them out tonight and get back to you. :) by the way.. do you maybe have a clue to why I get these warnings inside the music methods? especially the sharedSoundManager part of the music methods

Comment: t worked fine! thanks! :D hope to be able to return the help one day ;)